# Add row with zero value when in MySQL when record is not found for a particular month

Tags: mysql, sql, gaps-and-islands

It was hard to find a good title for my question.
I have 3 tables: `materials`, `orders` and `order_contents`.
There are 5 different types of materials in the `materials` table
The orders table contains the dates for the orders. Orders currently span over 4 months.
The orders are filled with materials in the table called `order_contents`.

I am trying to get the overall cost per month for materials and display them in a highchart.
Here's the query I run:

```
SELECT m.name, CONCAT(MONTH(o.order_date), '/', YEAR(o.order_date)) as `month`, SUM(oc.weight * m.price) AS cost
    FROM order_contents oc 
    INNER JOIN orders o ON oc.order_id = o.id
    INNER JOIN materials m ON oc.material_id = m.id
    GROUP BY MONTH(o.order_date), m.id
    ORDER BY m.name, order_date ASC
```

Here are the results:

[image]

The problem is that if a material isn't used in a particular month, it won't generate a record for it (obviously). So when I loop through the results and try to form the hightable data series, it won't fill a month with zero. For example, the material **Big Bag** is only consumed in January 2022, but since it's the only entry in the data series, it maps with the first month, which is August. I can add logic to fix this problem but I thought I'd ask here first if there is a way to reformat this query to yield the results I'm looking for.
Here's what I'd like to get:

[image]

I'm way out of my league here on SQL capabilities for this sort of problem.

Comment: What's your MySQL version? Please run `SELECT version();` to check.

Comment: @pilcrow Yes, it solves my problem, thank you. It's a bit more laborious than I wanted but I guess there really isn't a cleaner solution as MySQL won't just come out with rows out of the blue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a (probably wired) idea:

For a SQL table:

```sql
create table temp
(
    month int,
    year int,
    name varchar(16), -- something like material-type
    count int,
)
```

We could run:

```sql
select const_year.year, const_month.month, const_name.name, ifnull(count, 0)
from (select 1 month union
select 2 union
select 3 union
select 4 union
select 5 union
select 6 union
select 7 union
select 8 union
select 9 union
select 10 union
select 11 union
select 12) const_month -- now we have a list contains 12 months

left join (select 2020 year union
select 2021 union
select 2022 ) const_year
on true -- now we have a table contains all months between those years

left join (select distinct temp.name as name
from temp) const_name
on true -- join with all distinct names/types

left join (select temp.name as name, temp.year as year, temp.month as month, sum(count) as count
from temp
group by temp.year, temp.month, temp.name -- here is the real query for statistic
) statistic
on statistic.year = const_year.year
and statistic.month = const_month.month
and statistic.name = const_name.name

order by name, year, month -- order results if we need
```

I think there definitely have more better solution than this. Though it's working for some case.

Comment: Thanks. I had something like this in mind but I was hoping for a cleaner approach, something that MySQL is capable of that I'm not aware of.